# How to combine two arrays (`keys` and `values`) into an object using JMESPath?

Tags: jmespath

I have a JSON object with two arrays — one `keys` array and one `values` array, both of the same length. Using jmespath, I want to construct a new object using the values of the `keys` array as the keys and the values of the `values` array as the values, like [`array_combine`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) in PHP.

For example, here's the input:

```
{
    "keys": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    ],
    "values": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
}
```

And here is the output I'm expecting:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
}
```

Is there any built-in function to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is not possible yet.

Github issue: [jmespath.py#152](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/issues/152) — (*located in the repo of the Python implementation*)

You would need the `zip` and `from_items` functions, proposed **(!)** for the specs [in this github pull request](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.site/pull/21/files).

Answer (score -1):

**jmespath** is popular library to parse/query JSON files. More examples at http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html

In below code

- js is the provided json content
- jp.search('keys',json.loads(js)) produces the list : *[u'a', u'b', u'c']*
- jp.search('values',json.loads(js)) produces the list : *[1, 2, 3]*
- **zip** combines the two lists and **dict()** converts the tuples to a
  dictionary

  ```
  import json
  import jmespath

  js = '''{
          "keys": [
                  "a",
                  "b",
                  "c"
                  ],
          "values": [
                  1,
                  2,
                  3
                    ]
          }'''

  print (dict(zip(jp.search('keys',json.loads(js)),jp.search('values',json.loads(js)))))
  ```

  ***output: {u'a': 1, u'c': 3, u'b': 2}***

Comment: Please consider adding some wording to explain what you have done with the code.

Comment: Sure, added more details.

Comment: @Sai, I appreciate the effort, but I was looking for a solution that used jmespath only and your solution uses Python to zip the two arrays. The reason for wanting a jmespath-only approach is I want to build an API where users provide a jmespath script to reshape a JSON response to their liking without compromising the server by executing arbitrary Python code.