# Getting first level with JMESPath

Tags: json, jmespath

I have this JSON document:

```
{
"1": {
    "a": "G1"
},
"2": {
    "a": "GM1"
}
}
```

My expected result should be:

```
1,G1
2,GM1
```

With `*.a` i get

```
[
  "G1",
  "GM1"
]
```

but I am absolutely stuck for the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this expression worked 100% for me:

```
[{key1:keys(@)[0],a:*.a| [0]},{key1:keys(@)[1],a:*.a| [1]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly there is not much you can do that would be totally matching your use case and that would scale properly.

This is because JMESPath does not have a way to reference its parent, although [this has been requested before](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.js/issues/22#issuecomment-394157797), to allow you something like

```
*.[join(',', [keys($), a])]
```

---

You can definitely extract a list of keys and values, thanks to the function [`keys`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#keys):

```
@.{keys: keys(@), values: *.a}
```

That gives

```json
{
  "keys": [
    "1",
    "2"
  ],
  "values": [
    "G1",
    "GM1"
  ]
}
```

But then you just fall under the same case as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900580/how-to-combine-two-arrays-keys-and-values-into-an-object-using-jmespath), because `keys` will give you a list of keys.

---

You can also end with a list of lists:

```
@.[keys(@), *.a]
```

Will give you:

```json
[
  [
    "1",
    "2"
  ],
  [
    "G1",
    "GM1"
  ]
]
```

And you can even go further and [flatten](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#flatten-operator) it if needed:

```
@.[keys(@), *.a] []
```

Gives:

```json
[
  "1",
  "2",
  "G1",
  "GM1"
]
```

---

With all this if you do happen to have a list of **exactly two items**, then a solution would be to use a combination of [`join`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#join) and [slice](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#slices):

```
@.[join(',',[keys(@),*.a][] | [::2]), join(',',[keys(@),*.a][] | [1::2])]
```

That would give the expected:

```json
[
  "1,G1",
  "2,GM1"
]
```

But, sadly, as soon as you have more than two items to consider you would end up with a buggy:

```json
[
  "1,3,G1,GM3",
  "2,4,GM1,GM4"
]
```

With a data set of

```json
{
  "1": {
    "a": "G1"
  },
  "2": {
    "a": "GM1"
  },
  "3": {
    "a": "GM3"
  },
  "4": {
    "a": "GM4"
  }
}
```

---

And then, of course, the same can be achieved hardcoding indexes:

```
@.[join(',', [keys(@)[0], *.a | [0]]), join(',', [keys(@)[1], *.a | [1]])]
```

That also gives the expected:

```json
[
  "1,G1",
  "2,GM1"
]
```

But, sadly, this only works if you know in advance the number of rows that are going to be returned to you.

---

And if you want a single string, given that were you want to feed the data accepts `\n` as a new line, you can `join` he whole array again:

```
@.[join(',', [keys(@)[0], *.a | [0]]), join(',', [keys(@)[1], *.a | [1]])].join(`\n`,@)
```

Will give:

```json
"1,G1\n2,GM1"
```

Comment: Do you know, how to get rid of `[ ]` around the result `[
  "1,G1",
  "2,GM1"
]`?

Comment: You'll have to use join again to make a string out of a array, but you'll probably loose the new line and depending on where you want to feed it `\n` might work or not. Will add that to the answer.

Comment: You are right - using it in Google App Script i get an error `Request failed: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type string.` And this one `@.[join(',', [keys(@)[0], *.a | [0]]), join(',', [keys(@)[1], *.a | [1]])]` puts me both pairs into the same row of Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: This is weird btw: if i have one item, so `@.[join(',',[keys(@),*.a][] | [::2]), join(',',[keys(@),*.a][] | [1::2])]` puts id into A1 and name into B1l of Google Sheet. But if i have two items, same expression puts `1,G1` into A1 and `2,GM1` into B1.

Comment: Yes because slicing an array with a step of two makes it depend on a even number of items